# Typed Text Shows Late in Textfield of Material UI v4

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I have a list of TextFields on the page and user is able to type text into them. `data` is the whole dataset. Issue is like in the below gif, text shows few milliseconds after user typing. Why would that be? At first data was in Redux and I was directly communicating with that, now I moved to local usestate data, I tried useMemo, I tried useState separately like this only for notes fields `const [notes, setNotes] = useState(() => localData.map((office) => office.office?.notes || ""));`, still every time I type the data each letter sometimes show all at once and sometimes few hundred milliseconds late. I won't be able to simply move to material ui v5 just to fix this problem.

Image link is below I can't upload gifs here
https://s2.gifyu.com/images/Screen-Recording-2023-04-01-at-11.25.18-AM.gif

```
data.map((eachData, i) => {
  return (
    <TextField
      value={eachData?.notes || ""}
      onChange={(event) => updateOfficeData(i, event.target.value)}
    />
  );
});
```

update function is like

```
const updateData = (index, value) => {
  let newData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
  newData[index] = value;
  setData(newData);
};
```

Comment: Answer seems to be wrapping updateData with debounce function of lodash and using defaultValue prop instead of value prop for the TextField

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer seems to be wrapping updateData with debounce function of lodash and using defaultValue prop instead of value prop for the TextField